# Search API not returning hit

Tags: search-results, keywordquery

I have a problem where one of my documents does not show up in search. I have investigated with the REST API and found no evident wrongs.

Example:

Doing a search for `MyCustomProperty="Something is wrong"` returns 0 hits

But doing a search for `MyCustomProperty="Something*"` returns my document

By using REST API I can see in the latter case that `MyCustomProperty` is set to `Something is wrong`.

Why is it not returned in the first case?

Note that the first case works for the main part of document, but not for documents where `MyCustomProperty` is set to `Something is wrong`. `TrimDuplicates= false` does not help

Comment: space could be problem? what is the static name of custom property?

Comment: The custom property has no spaces, it is called AssociatedContentType. Other values with spaces works, but not some

Comment: can you just provide the value you are trying to search, if you don't mind

Comment: Did you try to encode the query string?

Comment: I have tried the same query (`MyCustomProperty="Something is wrong"`) from a search center, yields no results

Comment: are you putting double quotes while searching?

Comment: Yes I am, double quotes

Comment: in search center , without double quotes gives you same result?

Comment: Sadly, no difference with and without quotes

Comment: you have problem searching for only 1 document or many of them?

Comment: All that fullfills the MyCustomProperty="Something is wrong"

Comment: do you think it might be problem of stopword threshold by any chance?

Comment: Please tell me more :)

Comment: your case doesn't seems to be like that.but still you have a look at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191251(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, but no it does not feel applicable

Comment: @RobertLindgren Are you using /search/query with GET or POST method?

Comment: With rest I have used GET, but same goes for KeywordQuery from C# and search from search box

Comment: You can try to use POST.This method can be used to overcome URI length restrictions when using the GET

Comment: If it is not working from code behind with keywordquery, this will not help I'm afraid, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2013? Can you share the details of your search schema for the custom property? Is it configured to be "Queriable"? Try MyCustomProperty:"Something is wrong" for items where the property contains your value rather than items where the property equals your value. Also, is the property multi value aware?

Comment: This seems like a comment more than a question. It is indeed 2013, but the value equals what I put in the quotes.

Comment: Property is not, and should not be multi, it is queryable (since it works for most search strings..)

Answer (score 0):

Since MyCustomProperty="Something*" matched your document your managed property contains parts of your string but it doesn't equal your string. Did you try using :? Have you tried using wildcard with more search terms, i.e. MyCustomProperty="Something is*" or MyCustomProperty="Something is wrong*"? Is your query language and detected document language the same? I recommended the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool for debugging

Comment: By using the rest API I have make sure the languages match, and by using wildcard I can see that the value saved in the managed property is indeed the full value, but it is still not retuned using equal sign (even when copy pasting the actual value returned from a wild card search).

Comment: Using a query analyzer tool is not the solution since this do work for all but one value